# ¿Por qué mi variable LatLng regresa 0.0 si tiene asignado otro valor?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Estoy recibiendo coordenadas de un Json, y como están en un método tengo que declarar mi variable `LatLng` de forma global para que sea accesible a cualquier método, pero a la hora de correrlo me regresa (0.0,0.0) y no sé por qué si, en el Log("durango") me muestra que tiene asignados los valores que quiero, pero en el Log("ubicacion") me muestra que tiene (0.0,0.0).

```
public class BusinessPremium extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    LatLng durango = new LatLng(0.0, 0.0);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_business_premium);
        SupportMapFragment supportFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        supportFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        int value = bundle.getInt("no");

        new PlifRequestBase(BusinessPremium.this) {

            @Override
            public JsonObject onHttpOk(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {
                JsonObject data, details, location, geolocation, more, phoneNumber;
                JsonArray branches, phones;
                data = response;

                branches = data.get("branches").getAsJsonArray();
                details = branches.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
                location = details.get("location").getAsJsonObject();
                geolocation = details.get("geolocation").getAsJsonObject();

                phones = details.get("phones").getAsJsonArray();
                more = phones.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
                //phoneNumber = more.get("number").getAsJsonObject();

                //ids = data.get("id").getAsInt();
                final String name = data.get("name").getAsString();
                final String description = data.get("description").getAsString();
                final String category_image_cover = data.get("category_image_cover").getAsString();
                final String category_image_logo = data.get("category_image_logo").getAsString();
                final String street = location.get("street").getAsString();
                final String number = location.get("number").getAsString();
                final String neighborhood = location.get("neighborhood").getAsString();
                final String zip = location.get("zip").getAsString();
                final String municipality = location.get("municipality").getAsString();
                final String numberP = more.get("number").getAsString();
                final String latitude = geolocation.get("lat").getAsString();
                final String longitude = geolocation.get("lng").getAsString();

                durango = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));
                Log.d("Durango",String.valueOf(durango));
                final TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameBusiness);
                final TextView txtDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
                final ImageView txtCategory_image_cover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coverBusiness);
                final ImageView txtCategory_image_logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logoBusiness);
                final TextView txtAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
                final TextView txtPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone);

                BusinessPremium.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        txtName.setText(name);
                        txtDescription.setText(description);
                        Glide.with(BusinessPremium.this).load(category_image_cover).into(txtCategory_image_cover);
                        Glide.with(BusinessPremium.this).load(category_image_logo).into(txtCategory_image_logo);
                        txtAddress.setText(street + " " + number + "\n" + neighborhood + " " + zip + " " + municipality);
                        txtPhone.setText(numberP);
                    }

                });
                // Log.d("ID", String.valueOf(card));
                Log.d("Nombre", name);
                return data;
            }

            @Override
            public void onHttpCreate(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {

            }
        }.execute("businesses/" + String.valueOf(value), "GET");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng ubicacion=durango;
        // Add marker in Durango and move the camera
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ubicacion, 17));
        Log.d("ubicacion"String.valueOf(ubicacion));

        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ubicacion).title("Marker in Durango"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Has debugeado y mirado que donde haces **geolocation.get...** estas cogiendo el valor y no que no este haciendo nada y por eso siempre sea 0.0?

Comment: No, por eso tengo el log, para que me muestre en consola los valores y el log.d("Durango",String.valueof(durango) me muestra las coordenadas que quiero

Comment: onMapReady ocurre antes que onHttpOk, es por eso que le asignas 0,0 a ubicacion... verifica esto poniendo Log.d(TAG, "entre a onMapReady ") en la primera linea de onMapReady y Log.d(TAG, "entre a onHttpOk")  en la primera linea de onHttpOk

Comment: @Maguz si esta entrando primero a OnMapReady :/.... no sabes como hacer para que entre primero a HttpOk o como puedo asignarle los valores del json desde el principio? :/, pero de forma que pueda accesar desde cualquier metodo :/

Comment: @HeberSolis yo movería el onHttpOk de onCreate() a onResume(), pero no estoy seguro si es lo correcto.

Comment: Deberías imprimir primero el resultado de `longitude` y `latitude`, y quizás no hace bien la conversión de `String` a `Double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un problema de sincronización.

- En onCreate obtienes el LatLng de durango de forma asíncrona.
- onMapReady se llama cuando el mapa ha cargado, también es asíncrono

No puedes saber que código se va a ejecutar antes, así que deberías esperar a onMapReady para obtener los valores de LatLng después de éste.

Ejemplo:

```
public class BusinessPremium extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        private GoogleMap mMap;

        LatLng durango = new LatLng(0.0, 0.0);

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_business_premium);
            SupportMapFragment supportFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            supportFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            int value = bundle.getInt("no");

            // Aquí llamabas a getLatLng()
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            getLatLng();
        }

        private void addMarker(){
            LatLng ubicacion=durango;
            // Add marker in Durango and move the camera
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ubicacion, 17));

            Log.d("ubicacion" , String.valueOf(ubicacion));

            if (mMap != null) {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ubicacion).title("Marker in Durango"));
            }
        }

        private void getLatLng(){
            new PlifRequestBase(BusinessPremium.this) {

                @Override
                public JsonObject onHttpOk(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {
                    JsonObject data, details, location, geolocation, more, phoneNumber;
                    JsonArray branches, phones;
                    data = response;

                    branches = data.get("branches").getAsJsonArray();
                    details = branches.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
                    location = details.get("location").getAsJsonObject();
                    geolocation = details.get("geolocation").getAsJsonObject();

                    phones = details.get("phones").getAsJsonArray();
                    more = phones.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
                    //phoneNumber = more.get("number").getAsJsonObject();

                    //ids = data.get("id").getAsInt();
                    final String name = data.get("name").getAsString();
                    final String description = data.get("description").getAsString();
                    final String category_image_cover = data.get("category_image_cover").getAsString();
                    final String category_image_logo = data.get("category_image_logo").getAsString();
                    final String street = location.get("street").getAsString();
                    final String number = location.get("number").getAsString();
                    final String neighborhood = location.get("neighborhood").getAsString();
                    final String zip = location.get("zip").getAsString();
                    final String municipality = location.get("municipality").getAsString();
                    final String numberP = more.get("number").getAsString();
                    final String latitude = geolocation.get("lat").getAsString();
                    final String longitude = geolocation.get("lng").getAsString();

                    durango = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double.parseDouble(longitude));
                    Log.d("Durango",String.valueOf(durango));
                    final TextView txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameBusiness);
                    final TextView txtDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
                    final ImageView txtCategory_image_cover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coverBusiness);
                    final ImageView txtCategory_image_logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logoBusiness);
                    final TextView txtAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
                    final TextView txtPhone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone);

                    BusinessPremium.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            txtName.setText(name);
                            txtDescription.setText(description);
                            Glide.with(BusinessPremium.this).load(category_image_cover).into(txtCategory_image_cover);
                            Glide.with(BusinessPremium.this).load(category_image_logo).into(txtCategory_image_logo);
                            txtAddress.setText(street + " " + number + "\n" + neighborhood + " " + zip + " " + municipality);
                            txtPhone.setText(numberP);
                            addMarker();
                        }

                    });
                    // Log.d("ID", String.valueOf(card));
                    Log.d("Nombre", name);
                    return data;
                }

                @Override
                public void onHttpCreate(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {

                }
            }.execute("businesses/" + String.valueOf(value), "GET");
        }
    }
```

Aún así la estructura no es muy correcta, deberías crear una clase a parte para obtener el LatLng y una vez lo hagas enviarte la información a esta clase de vuelta a través de un Listener.

Comment: Muchas gracias! esto era el problema! muchas muchas gracias :)